# AppleScript mail formatting

Tags: macos, applescript, filemaker

Because FileMaker Pro doesn't support RTF/HTML formatting of the emails it creates I have created an AppleScript to format the email. It works! However it only seems to format the first instance of each variable it encounters in the script. Any pointers gladly accepted.

```
tell application "FileMaker Pro"
set field_a to cell "Email::emailText_1" of layout "Email"
set field_b to cell "Email::emailText_2" of layout "Email"
set field_c to cell "Email::emailText_3" of layout "Email"
set field_d to cell "Email::emailText_4" of layout "Email"
set field_e to cell "Email::emailText_5" of layout "Email"
set field_f to cell "Email::emailText_6" of layout "Email"
set field_g to cell "Email::emailText_7" of layout "Email"
set theAttachment to cell "Email::attachmentPath_cleaned"
end tell

set the_content to (field_a & field_b & field_c & " ?? " & field_d & field_e & field_f & field_b & field_g & " ?? " & field_c)

tell application "Mail"
activate
set theSignature to "signature 1"
set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:field_a & " text here " & startDate & " to " & endDate, content:the_content}
set message signature of msg to signature theSignature
tell msg
    make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:"blurred_out@blurry_text.com"}
    make new cc recipient at end of cc recipients with properties {address:"blurred_out@blurry_text.com"}
    make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment as alias}

    set x to offset of field_b in the_content
    set font of characters (x - 1) thru (x + (count of field_b)) of content to "Helvetica Bold"

    set x to offset of field_d in the_content
    set font of characters (x - 1) thru (x + (count of field_d)) of content to "Helvetica Bold"

    set x to offset of field_f in the_content
    set font of characters (x - 1) thru (x + (count of field_f)) of content to "Helvetica Bold"

    set x to offset of field_g in the_content
    set font of characters (x - 1) thru (x + (count of field_g)) of content to "Helvetica Bold"

    set x to offset of "??" in the_content
    set font of characters (x - 1) thru (x + (count of "??")) of content to "Helvetica Bold"
end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to solve is defining 2 new variables for the second instances of `field_b` and `field_c`:

```
set field_b1 to cell "Email::emailText_2" of layout "Email"
set field_c1 to cell "Email::emailText_3" of layout "Email"

set the_content to (field_a & field_b & field_c & " ?? " & field_d & field_e & field_f & field_b1 & field_g & " ?? " & field_c1)

set x to offset of field_b1 in the_content
set font of characters (x - 1) thru (x + (count of field_b1)) of content to "Helvetica Bold"

set x to offset of field_c1 in the_content
set font of characters (x - 1) thru (x + (count of field_c1)) of content to "Helvetica Bold"
```

Comment: Seems simple enough but unfortunately AppleScript doesn't fall for it. The second instance remains unchanged.